# Hadoop mapreduce - reducer not running

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, reducers

I am trying to customize bulk load map-reduce into HBase, and I ran into issues with reducer. First I thought I didn't write the reducer well, but upon throwing runtime exception in reducer and seeing the code working, I realized that the reducer is not running at all. 
So far I don't see any thing wrong with some of common answers to this problem;

1. My configuration has mapoutput and output separate
2. My reducer and mapper has override
3. I have Iterable, and my reducer input is (writable, put), so...

Here's my code:

Driver

```
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int result=0;
    String outputPath = args[1];
    Configuration configuration = getConf();
    configuration.set("data.seperator", DATA_SEPERATOR);
    configuration.set("hbase.table.name",TABLE_NAME);
    configuration.set("COLUMN_FAMILY_1",COLUMN_FAMILY_1);
    Job job = new Job(configuration);
    job.setJarByClass(HBaseBulkLoadDriver.class);
    job.setJobName("Bulk Loading HBase Table::"+TABLE_NAME);
    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(ImmutableBytesWritable.class);
    job.setMapperClass(HBaseBulkLoadMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(HBaseBulkLoadReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(ImmutableBytesWritable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Put.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPaths(job, args[0]);
    FileSystem.getLocal(getConf()).delete(new Path(outputPath), true);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(outputPath));
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Put.class);
    job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
    HFileOutputFormat.configureIncrementalLoad(job, new HTable(configuration,TABLE_NAME));
    job.waitForCompletion(true);
```

Mapper

```
public class HBaseBulkLoadMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, ImmutableBytesWritable, Put> {
    private String hbaseTable;
    private String dataSeperator;
    private String columnFamily1;
    private ImmutableBytesWritable hbaseTableName;

    public void setup(Context context) {
        Configuration configuration = context.getConfiguration();
        hbaseTable = configuration.get("hbase.table.name");
        dataSeperator = configuration.get("data.seperator");
        columnFamily1 = configuration.get("COLUMN_FAMILY_1");
        hbaseTableName = new ImmutableBytesWritable(Bytes.toBytes(hbaseTable));
    }
        @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) {
        try {
            String[] values = value.toString().split(dataSeperator);
            String rowKey = values[0];
            Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(rowKey));
            BUNCH OF ADDS;
            context.write(new ImmutableBytesWritable(Bytes.toBytes(rowKey)), put);
        } catch(Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Reducer

```
public class HBaseBulkLoadReducer extends Reducer<ImmutableBytesWritable, Put, ImmutableBytesWritable, Put> {
      @Override
      protected void reduce(
          ImmutableBytesWritable row,
          Iterable<Put> puts,
          Reducer<ImmutableBytesWritable, Put,
                  ImmutableBytesWritable, Put>.Context context)
          throws java.io.IOException, InterruptedException
      {
        TreeMap<String,KeyValue> map = new TreeMap<String,KeyValue>();
        int count =0;
        Append nkv;
        byte[] tmp= "".getBytes();
        Put pp = new Put(tmp);
    try{
        for (Put p : puts) {
              byte[] r =  "".getBytes();
              //KeyValue kv = new KeyValue(r);
              if (count!=0){
              r = p.getRow();
              pp.add(new KeyValue(r));
              //KeyValue k = map.get(row.toString());
              //nkv = new Append(k.getRowArray());
              //nkv=nkv.add(kv);
              //map.put(row.toString(), k.clone());
              //context.write(row,nkv);
              //tmp=ArrayUtils.addAll(tmp,kv.getValueArray());
              //map.put(row.toString(),new KeyValue(kv.getRowArray(),kv.getFamilyArray(),kv.getQualifierArray(),tmp));
              count++;
              throw new RuntimeException();
              }
              else{
              r = p.getRow();
              pp = new Put(row.toString().getBytes());
              pp.add(new KeyValue(r));
              //tmp=kv.clone().getValueArray();
              //nkv = new Append(kv.getRowArray());
              //map.put(row.toString(), kv.clone());
              count++;
              throw new RuntimeException();
          }
     }
      context.write(row,pp);
      }catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();}
     }

}
```

Well I know reducer is kinda messy but the thing is, it has runtimeException on both if and else clauses as you can see and the bulk load succeeds, so I am quite sure that the reducer is not running - and I am not sure why. All three files are maven packaged in same directory, FYI.

Comment: Why do you implicitly `throw new RuntimeException();`?

Comment: He was trying to see if the block even executed... "but upon throwing runtime exception in reducer and seeing the code working, I realized that the reducer is not running at all"

Comment: I think the reducer should run based on `job.setNumReduceTasks(1)` but if   `Iterable<Put> puts` is empty, then the for loop of the reducer won't be entered and those exceptions won't be thrown

Comment: Are you sure the map phase executes successfully?

Comment: The only thing I can imagine is that they `for` block is never entered, meaning the `Iterable<Put> puts` could be empty.

Comment: Map phase executes, it loads data into hbase table as it supposed to. Although, because reducer never worked, it just overwrites one another when they have same row key, which is what I am trying to achieve in reducer.

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 Just ran the code again with runtime exception right below the try clause, and the job executed successfully. It loaded and overwrote stuff as before. looks like reduce is not run at all, which is wierd cuz it tells me map 100% reduce 100% when I run the job...

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 Upon further probing, found out that throwing runtime exception on mapper fails the operation silently - it just doesn't generate Hfile, so I know it failed.

Comment: Looking at log, can see mapper runtime exceptions but not reducers... interesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what was wrong. configureincrementalload sets the reducer class to putsort or keyvaluesort according to output values, so if I want to use a custom reducer class I have to set it after configureincrementalload. After that I could see reducer running. Just answering my own question so it may help people who run into same problem.

```
HFileOutputFormat.configureIncrementalLoad(job, new HTable(configuration,TABLE_NAME));
job.setReducerClass(HBaseBulkLoadReducer.class);
job.waitForCompletion(true);
```